# Expo Notifications addNotificationReceivedListener not being called in foreground only on Android standalone

Tags: android, expo, react-native, expo-notifications

I am trying to receive notifications in my Expo app. I can successfully register a token, and the notification is received fine when the app is **not** foregrounded. However, on Android only the `addNotificationReceivedListener` callback is not being triggered. This works fine on iOS when the app is foregrounded and Android, only when the app is not foregrounded.
Here is my code for registering the callback.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
         handleNotification: async () => ({
            shouldShowAlert: true,
            shouldPlaySound: true,
            shouldSetBadge: false,
         }),
      });
      Notifications.addNotificationReceivedListener(() => {
         dispatch(setBalance({ amount: null }));
      });
   }, []);
```

And here is my app.json

```
{
   "name": "AppName",
   "displayName": "AppName",
   "expo": {
      "name": "AppName",
      "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
      "slug": "slug",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
      "scheme": "appscheme",
      "android": {
         "package": "com.appdomain",
         "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true,
         "versionCode": 7,
         "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
         "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
         "permissions": ["RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"]
      },
      "ios": {
         "bundleIdentifier": "com.appdomain",
         "buildNumber": "7"
      }
   }
}
```

I am using Expo 41 which I just upgraded to from 40. It was not working on 40 either. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may have android.useNextNotificationsApi set to true in app.json.